# Haskell Cabal: omitting version a big mistake

Tags: haskell, cabal

I ran `cabal build` on a `*.cabal` file that doesn't have a `version:` specified and it seems to have confused cabal. When I put back the version specification, I got

```
$ cabal build
Resolving dependencies...
TODO: add support for multiple packages in a directory.  Got
yah-0.1.0.0
yah-0.1.0.0

CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at src\\Distribution\\Client\\ProjectOrchestration.hs:586:9 in cabal-install-3.8.1.0-inplace:Distribution.
Client.ProjectOrchestration
```

That is, normally the `yah.cabal` file would read

```
cabal-version:      3.0
name:               yah
version:            0.1.0.0
license:        etc., etc.
```

and `cabal build` was fed the above without the `version` and maybe without the `cabal-version` -- not sure. In any case, starting over with `cabal init` doesn't fix it, but other projects can be compiled fine.

My guess is that the various modules that are in the `yah` project are registered somewhere/somehow and it's not clear how to expunge that and start over. I'm on Windows, cabal 3.8.1.0. I've looked in `C:\cabal`, `C:\ghccup`, `C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\cabal`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you have more than one `.cabal` file in that directory. Remove the one that's not named `yah.cabal`.

Comment: Wow, trying to fix things, I made it worse by saving backups. That was it. Thanks.

Comment: @RandallFairman never make ad-hoc backup files in a local directory. Use version control software for safely doing experimental changes. Backups should go to a remote server or at least a dedicated hard disk. (And even that should, at least for code, be done through the VCS, not by manual copying.)